# libgdx access tile properties in other layer

Tags: properties, libgdx, tile, tiled

I'm working on a project based with libgdx
I use Tiled to create map, so I have 2 layers: background / foreground.

background is the 1st layer
foreground the second.

In the second, I added a tile with "finish" property. Then I want to access on it when my player move on it.

This my Player class :

```html
package com.worms.game.entities;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Player extends Sprite implements InputProcessor {
 
 /** The movement velocity */
 private Vector2 velocity = new Vector2();
 
 private float speed = 300 * 2, gravity = 600 * 1.0f;
 
 private TiledMapTileLayer collisionLayer;
 
 private boolean canJump;
 
 public Player(Sprite sprite, TiledMapTileLayer collisionLayer) {
  super(sprite);
  this.collisionLayer = collisionLayer;
 }
 
 @Override
 public void draw(Batch batch) {
  update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
  super.draw(batch);
 }
 
 public void update(float delta) {
  // Applique la gravite
  this.velocity.y -= gravity * delta;
  
  // Clamp velocity
  if(this.velocity.y > speed) {
   this.velocity.y = speed;
  } else if(this.velocity.y < -speed) {
   this.velocity.y = -speed;
  }
  
  // On sauvegarde les old positions en cas de colisions
  float oldX = getX(), oldY = getY(), tileWidth = this.collisionLayer.getTileWidth(), tileHeight = this.collisionLayer.getTileHeight();
  boolean collisionX = false, collisionY = false, finish = false;
  
  // move on x
  setX(getX() + this.velocity.x * delta);
  
  if(this.velocity.x < 0) {
   // top left   
   collisionX = this.collisionLayer.getCell((int) (getX() / tileWidth), (int) ((getY() / getHeight()) / tileHeight)).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("blocked");
   
   // middle left
   if(!collisionX) {
    collisionX = this.collisionLayer.getCell((int) (getX() / tileWidth), (int) ((getY() + getHeight() / 2) / tileHeight)).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("blocked");
   }
   
   // bottom left
   if(!collisionX) {
    collisionX = this.collisionLayer.getCell((int) (getX() / tileWidth), (int) (getY()  / tileHeight)).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("blocked");
   }

  } else if(this.velocity.x > 0) {
   // top right
   collisionX = this.collisionLayer.getCell((int) ((getX() + getWidth()) / tileWidth), (int) ((getY() + getHeight()) / tileHeight)).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("blocked");

   // middle right
   if(!collisionX) {
    collisionX = this.collisionLayer.getCell((int) ((getX() + getWidth()) / tileWidth), (int) ((getY() + getWidth() / 2) / tileHeight)).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("blocked");
   }
   
   // bottom right
   if(!collisionX) {
    collisionX = this.collisionLayer.getCell((int) ((getX() + getWidth()) / tileWidth), (int) (getY() / tileHeight)).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("blocked");
   }
   
  }
  
  /**
   * En cas de collision
   * On remet le personnage à sa place initiale
   * On remet sa vitesse a 0
   */
  if(collisionX) {
   setX(oldX);
   this.velocity.x = 0;
  }
  
  
  // move on y
  setY(getY() + this.velocity.y * delta);
  

  if(this.velocity.y < 0) { // going down
   // bottom left   
   collisionY = this.collisionLayer.getCell((int) (getX() / tileWidth), (int) (getY() / tileHeight)).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("blocked");
   
   //bottom middle
   if(!collisionY) {
    collisionY = this.collisionLayer.getCell((int) ((getX() + getWidth() / 2) / tileWidth), (int) (getY() / tileHeight)).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("blocked");
   }
   
   // bottom right
   if(!collisionY) {
    collisionY = this.collisionLayer.getCell((int) ((getX() + getWidth()) / tileWidth), (int) (getY() / tileHeight)).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("blocked");
   }
   
   this.canJump = collisionY;
  } else if(this.velocity.y > 0) { // going up
   // top left
   collisionY = this.collisionLayer.getCell((int) (getX() / tileWidth), (int) ((getY() + getHeight()) / tileHeight)).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("blocked");

   // top middle
   if(!collisionY) {
    collisionY = this.collisionLayer.getCell((int) ((getX() + getWidth() / 2) / tileWidth), (int) ((getY() + getHeight()) / tileHeight)).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("blocked");
   }
   
   // top right
   if(!collisionY) {
    collisionY = this.collisionLayer.getCell((int) ((getX() + getWidth()) / tileWidth), (int) ((getY() + getHeight()) / tileHeight)).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("blocked");
   }
  }
  
  /**
   * En cas de collision
   * On remet le personnage à sa place initiale
   * On remet sa vitesse a 0
   */
  if(collisionY) {
   setY(oldY);
   this.velocity.y = 0;
  }
    
 }

 public Vector2 getVelocity() {
  return velocity;
 }

 public void setVelocity(Vector2 velocity) {
  this.velocity = velocity;
 }

 public float getSpeed() {
  return speed;
 }

 public void setSpeed(float speed) {
  this.speed = speed;
 }

 public float getGravity() {
  return gravity;
 }

 public void setGravity(float gravity) {
  this.gravity = gravity;
 }

 public TiledMapTileLayer getCollisionLayer() {
  return collisionLayer;
 }

 public void setCollisionLayer(TiledMapTileLayer collisionLayer) {
  this.collisionLayer = collisionLayer;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
  switch(keycode) {
   case Keys.Z:
    if(canJump) {
     this.velocity.y = speed;
     canJump = false;
    }
    break;
   case Keys.Q:
    this.velocity.x = -speed;
    break;
   case Keys.D:
    this.velocity.x = speed;
    break;
  }
  
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
  switch(keycode) {
   case Keys.Q:
   case Keys.D:
    this.velocity.x = 0;
    break;
  }
  
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 }
 
 
 
 
}
```

on "move on x" => "middle right"
I want to check if the close tile has "finish" property

The "this.collisionlayer" represents the background, passing in argument " (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get("background")" in my Play class.

if I put an other argument " (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get("foreground") ", and want to check by the same method, I got an exception : java.lang.NullPointerException

If I put the same tile in my background layer, I can access to his property, but not in my second layer.

What is the best method to do it ?

Sry for my bad english.

Thanks for all

Comment: Could you try accessing the layer by index? i.e. `map.getLayers().get(1)`

Comment: Yes, but I have the impression that my second layer is just 1 tile in the whole map. So when I want to check with the index , I got the exception NullPointer.. I dont know if I have to put a transparent background in my second layer or something else..

Comment: So just to clarify: are you getting your error when accessing the layer with `map.getLayers().get()` or when you try to access the cell in that layer?

Comment: When I want to get the cell , such as collisionX but for the second layer

Comment: If you check the layer with an index where there is no tile, you will get a nullpointer exception. Just check if the cell is null first.

Comment: Before checking for the collision test `if (this.collisionLayer.getCell((int) ((getX() + getWidth()) / tileWidth), (int) ((getY() + getWidth() / 2) / tileHeight)).getTile() != null)`